# If steady states of a dynamic system exist only as limits, are they actually steady states?

Tags: limits, nonlinear-system, stability-theory, nonlinear-dynamics, steady-state

I have a nonlinear dynamic model in discrete time. A simplified version of my dynamic system is:

\begin{equation}
x_{t+1} = \frac{1}{1 + \exp(f(x_t))}
\end{equation}

where $$f(x_t) = −\beta \left(2d \left(c+ \frac{1−c}{1+a(1−x_t)d} \right)−b−d \right)$$ with $\beta \geq 0$, $a > 0$, $d > b > 0$ and  $0 \leq c \leq 1$.

I know that if $c$ is greater than a certain threshold, $\exp( f(x_t) )$ converges to 0 and $x_{t+1}$ converges to 1, thus:

\begin{equation}
lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} (x_{t+1}) = 1
\end{equation}

If $c$ is smaller than a certain threshold, $\exp(f(x_t))$ goes to $\infty$ and $x_{t+1}$ converges to 0, thus:

\begin{equation}
lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} (x_{t+1}) = 0. 
\end{equation}

(I proved the two statements above by imposing $\exp(f(x_t))<\epsilon$ and $\exp(f(x_t)) >\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, respectively, where $\epsilon$ is a sufficiently small positive number, and solving for $c$).

However, $x_{t+1} = 1$ and $x_{t+1} = 0$ do not exist. So I am wondering the following:

1. can these two points ($x_{t+1} = 1$ and $x_{t+1} = 0$) be considered steady states of the system? Or they have to be defined in a different way (e.g. fixed points, or limit fixed points?)
2. How can I prove their existence and stability?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the function $f$? Does it have singularities?

Comment: $f(x_t) = - \beta \left(2d (c +\frac{1 - c}{1 + a(1 - x_t) d}) - b - d\right)$, where $\beta \geq 0$, $d,a,b > 0$ and $0 \leq c \leq 1$. Thanks!

Comment: How do you know that the system converges to those values and what values for the parameters are you considering in your simulations?

Comment: I know that if $c$ is greater than a certain threshold, $f(x_t)$ converges to 0 and $x_{t+1}$ converges to 1; if $c$ is smaller than a certain threshold, $f(x_t)$ goes to $\infty$ and $x_{t+1}$ converges to 0. I proved it by imposing $f(x_t) < \epsilon$ and $f(x_t) > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$, respectively, where $\epsilon$ is a sufficiently small positive number, and solving for $c$. However I am not sure whether I can consider these two points steady states or what are they..

Comment: This is not possible. If $f(x_t)$ converges to 0, that means that its exponential converges to 1 and the state converges to $1/2$. Also $f(x_t)$ goes to $+\infty$ is not possible since per your assumption $1-c\ge0$, $\beta>0$ and the only way it goes to infinity is that $x$ approaches to a value that makes $1+a(1-x_t)d=0$. So, I guess there are issues  in your calculations or in what you wrote in the comments. Please also update your post everything there is a new information.

Comment: Yes you are right sorry. I meant: if $c$ is greater than a certain threshold, $\exp( f(x_t) )$ converges to 0 and $x_{t+1}$ converges to 1; if $c$ is smaller than a certain threshold, $\exp(f(x_t))$ goes to $\infty$ and $x_{t+1}$ converges to 0. I proved it by imposing $\exp(f(x_t))<\epsilon$ and $\exp(f(x_t)) >\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, respectively, where $\epsilon$ is a sufficiently small positive number, and solving for $c$. However I am not sure whether I can consider these two points steady states or what are they..

Comment: That's not possible. If $x$ approaches $1$ then $f(x)$ approaches $f(1)$, which is a finite constant and you cannot have what you say. Same comment for the point 0.

Comment: But if the finite constant is large enough, it is possible that $x_{t+1} \rightarrow 1$, no? This is what I observe numerically..

Comment: Then, share what those values are.

Comment: E.g. if you plot $x_{t+1}$ as a function of $x_t$ with these values: $\beta = 1$, $a = 1$,  $b  = 0.24$,  $d = 10$ and you let $c$ vary between 0 and 1, the dynamics will have one "steady state" at 1 and another one (if $c < 0.2$) at 0.

Comment: Ok it is funny. This is fine tuned so that the exponential takes very large values that go beyond machine precision and everything collapses to zero or one because of that. Those points 0 and 1 are not equilibrium points per say. The trajectories approach them but do not converge to those values. Another phenomenon is that $f$ is pretty much constant in a neighborhood of zero and this turns the dynamical system into a trivial dynamical system $x^+=c$ where $c$ is close to zero. Those values are not equilibrium points but some sort of artefacts, somehow.

Comment: I don't fully understand your comment: this is an economics model we built to study a certain phenomenon, the values are taken from data; also, as far as I understand, the more $t$ increases, the more $x_{t+1}$ approaches 0 or 1, meaning that the distance bw $x_{t+1}$ and 1 or 0 gets smallre and smaller, no? Why do you say that the trajectories do not converge to 0 and 1? And how would you define 0 and 1?

Comment: You need to look at dynamical systems theory, equilibrium points, and stability theory. What you have here is a fun artifact arising from the combination of the exponential and the special form of the function $f$, that turn the system into a non dynamical system. Converging to zero or one, mean getting closer and closer at every step. You do not seem to get that here. You go for sure to a value close to one but it is impossible to identify this value by simulation due to finite machine precision.

Comment: Ok I get it, thank you very much. Just to understand: I can say that this system converges to a certain $x^*$ which is "very close" to (but different from) 1 or 0, right? Can I call these  $x^*$ "steady states"?

Answer (score 1):

An equilibrium point or a fixed-point is a state-value for which the dynamics does not change anymore. For a continuous-time system $\dot{x}=g(x)$, the equilibrium points are the state values $x^*$ for which we have $g(x^*)=0$. For a discrete-time system $x^+=g(x)$, the equilibrium points are the state values $x^*$ for which we have $g(x^*)=g^*$.

In your case, $x^*=0$ can not be equilibrium point because that would mean that $1/(1+\exp(f(0)))=0$, which is not possible.

Similarly, the point $x^*=1$ can not be an equilibrium point since we would require $1/(1+\exp(f(1)))=1$, which is not possible.

However, it is possible that other equilibro points exist and, for that, you will need to find the solution to $x^*=1/(1+\exp(f(x^*)))$. You will need to find them numerically.

Their local stability can be analyzed by linearizing the system about that equilibrium points.

---

For certain values of the parameters, it turns out that when we enter a neighborhood of 0, then $f(x)\approx \omega>>0$ there and $c$ is sufficiently large. This value will be amplified by the exponential function. So, in that case we have that

$$x^+=\dfrac{1}{1+\exp(f(x))}\approx \dfrac{1}{1+\exp(\omega)}\approx 0$$

but the trajectories do not converge to zero. They will stay in a neighborhood of zero.

The same reasoning applies to the point 1 with the difference that $\omega<<0$.

---

For a convergence to 0, a necessary condition would be that $f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to0$ whereas for a convergence to 1, you will need to have that $f(x)\to-\infty$ as $x\to1$.

Comment: Thank you! I will wait for the complete answer. So you think that these points are not steady states? How would you call these points where the system goes eventually? Limit fixed points or anything like that? Thanks again